# Why mutation probabiltiy is powered by one third?

Tags: genetic-algorithm, mutation, jenetics

In jenetics library, following code is given in alter() methid of Mutator class:

final double p = pow(_probability, 1.0/3.0);

Can anyone please explain the purpose of calculating this new probabilty for mutation? How is it beneficial? How can we use this class to implement One-Position or Point Mutation?

Ref:https://github.com/jenetics/jenetics/blob/master/org.jenetics/src/main/java/org/jenetics/Mutator.java

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the hierarchical structure of Population -> Genotype -> Chromosome -> Gene. Since the given probability is the mutation probability of a single Gene and you first have to select one Genotype out of the Population. Then you select one Chromosome out of the selected Genotype. At last, the Gene is selected from the Chromosome. The selection probability of the single selection steps is set to pow(p, 1/3), which leads to the desired Gene mutation probability of p.

This mechanism is also described in the [Jenetics Manual](http://jenetics.io/manual/manual-3.0.1.pdf) in paragraph "Mutator" on page 13.